# How to keep an element on screen after css3 animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So, I'm working on an interactive menu with a grid of images that flip over and reveal info with links on the back side. You can see a live demo of what I'm trying to do here [Card Flip Demo](http://46.101.194.36/sdg-demo/). What I want to be able to do, is make sure that the flipped and zoomed element is fully visible on the screen. At the moment, the only flipping element is largely off-screen after the animation.

Is there any way to achieve this with more general css rules, or do I have to specify the end position for each flipped element (or at least the one's that will end up off screen? What I'd like to achieve is the element getting placed completely on-screen, somewhere close to it's original position.

Here's the html

```
<div class="sdgs">
<div class="flip">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="images/SDG_ICONS/SDG01.png" alt="No Poverty" width="140" height="140" />
    </div>
    <div class="back">
    <h3><a>ARED</a></h3>
    <h3><a>AgroCenta</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#Tilly">Tilly's Farm</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css

```
.sdgs{
-webkit-perspective:650px;
perspective:650px;
}
.front, .back{
height:140px;
width:140px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip{
position: relative;
height:140px;
width:140px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
transition: all 0.8s ease;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip:hover{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
}
.front, .back{
height:140px;
width:140px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
filter: blur(0);
}
.back{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: This would be tricky to achieve with general rules because you are scaling the element. When you scale an element, its dimensions are obviously going to be more than the original one. So the items which are near the corners will fully/partially go out of view.

Comment: Ok, then how can I achieve this for a single element?

Comment: Do you mean (for example) just for the one on top-left of your page?

Comment: Yes, well technically "how can I specify a different final position of the elements after a the rotation"?

Comment: Depending on the position of your element, you can choose an appropriate value for `transform-origin` like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lxq7g3j/). I have added two boxes on either side for example. If you are ok with this as solution, I can add a few more examples to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Harry, that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Actually even setting `transform-origin` would cause problems when the layout changes due to screen sizes etc. For example an image which is on right edge of the page in a wide screen could go to second line and left edge on smaller screen. So, the ideal approach would be for you to avoid the scale or keep it as minimal as possible. Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lxq7g3j/1/) in different screen sizes and you'll know what I mean. When there are four (and only four) images per line it would work well but not at other times.

Comment: duly noted, and much appreciated.